# Can't I view Real Time users on firebase?

Tags: google-analytics, firebase, firebase-analytics

I used to use Admob analytics to view my users activity. There I was able to view real time app running users. Now when I upgraded to the Firebase, I don't find any real time user stats.

Does firebase has real time users stat feature? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There currently is no equivalent to Google Analytics' real time tracking of user information available in Firebase Analytics.

**Update (February 2017)**: Firebase added [DebugView](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview) to its Analytics product. This allows you to see a near realtime stream of the events from a specific device. Note that (as its name implies) this feature is most useful for debugging whether you have instrumented your code correctly. It is not the same as the realtime analytics in Google Analytics.

Comment: Sir, is there a chance for this feature to arrive soon?

Comment: Wondering the same

Comment: March, 2017 : This answer is obsolete, the answer of @quarezz is the right one.

Comment: @Christophe while DebugView shows near real time events, it is a different use-case than what OP asked for. I added some info to my answer to explain the difference.

Comment: April 2017: Now you can see Production real users (not only debug test devices) with StreamView like @mpolat said. https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7229836?hl=en

Comment: @VitoValov StreamView has also been generally available since February. But StreamView relies on the regular interval of when devices send their analytics events to the Firebase servers. DebugView on the other hand send the analytics events from the device to the servers almost immediately, making it much more suitable for debug purposes. Also see https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html

Comment: i think it is better to stick with Google Analytics till firebase becomes really real time (without 30mins delay).

Comment: There is no way to get the screen tracking live data?

Answer (score 6):

You can see realtime users and events at StreamView in Firebase.
StreamView shows you who is using your app and what they are doing, in real time. 
if you properly integrated the Firebase Analytics SDK in your app, StreamView tab will be visible in your Firebase Analytics.

[Sample Screen from StreamView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVOJM.jpg)

Detailed Information from Google Support : https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7229836?hl=en

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. At a minimum provide the relevant 'meat' of the information found in the linked content.

Answer (score 4):

You can now see realtime events in DebugView option at the console. Pretty neat feature, works great. Here is an example: [Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TJEB.png)

See more info at https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview

Answer (score 3):

As Frank van Puffelen replied, currently there is no realtime information available in Firebase Analytics dashboard. Until this feature is available your next best option is to enable debug logging as defined in the developer documentation:

iOS: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/start#next_steps

Android: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events#view_events_in_the_android_studio_debug_log

When you log event and the event data is uploaded you will see something like this (Android):

```
I/FA      : App measurement is starting up, version: 9080
I/FA      : To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
V/FA      : Logging event: origin=auto,name=_f,params=Bundle[{_c=1}]
V/FA      : Uploading data. app, uncompressed size, data: com.example.app, 348, 
V/FA      : batch {
V/FA      :   bundle {
V/FA      :     protocol_version: 1
V/FA      :     platform: android
V/FA      :     gmp_version: 9080
...
```

Comment: Do you know about any information that Google planned implemting the real time feature? Otherwise I think it's better to implement Google Analytics again.

Answer (score 2):

Latest Update from Firebase Dev Summit from Berlin.Firebase announced Debug view which will display raw data real time updates.

Currently i do not see it in my Firebase console,but hope it will be live for all users soon.

Comment: Firebase has revealed further information on DebugView in the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview

Comment: link to video about debugView https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zssCC6rXyGk&t=22m40s

Comment: As announced in the [Firebase Blog article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html), DebugView is now in closed beta, anyone can sign-up [here](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/debugview-blog/) if interested.